# how to drag a plot symbol on a graph to different position so that the graph reloads again with that position change in coreplot ios

Tags: ios5, core-plot

Wt I done is I drawn the scatter plot with the default plot data values. What I want to do is when I drag any of the plot symbol on the scatter line I want to reload the graph with that plot position change.

I am not getting any idea how to do it. Can anyone suggest me how to start up with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a plot space delegate to track the interaction using the pointing device down, up, and dragged methods. When the user drags a plot point, call `-reloadDataInIndexRange:` to reload the point being moved. The plot will then query the datasource for the updated position.